# How to exclude south migrations from public repositories?

Tags: django, git, version-control, django-south

I am using South to manage schema and data migrations on my development and production environments. As such I keep my migrations in my git repository so changes I make in development are properly migrated in production.

The apps and projects I am developing are currently private and only developed by me. At some point, I would like to publish/distribute my apps. I am assuming that at that point, I will have a "final" schema and therefor won't "need" South. Since these apps haven't been distributed before (except on my environments), the public version won't need the migrations that I used while developing the apps.

I have a two parter question:

1. Is it good (or acceptable) to remove or at least "clean up" the migrations based on my assumptions?
  What's the best way of doing so? I imagine keeping a branch for the public/distributed base could work, but I'm fairly new to git, so I don't know what my options are.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common point of confusion for people dealing with South and version control. You should, of course, commit migrations with your project, as others will need to run the same migrations themselves. However, you should clean up your migrations before committing them, which is actually deceptively easy.

If it's a brand new app or a brand new project in general:

1. Rollback the app to "zero":

   ```
   python manage.py migrate myapp zero
   ```
2. Delete all migrations for the app (Everything in the "migrations" directory except `__init__.py`).
3. Generate a new initial migration:

   ```
   python manage.py schemamigration --initial myapp
   ```

If it's an existing app, then the process is largely the same, but you're only going to rollback to *just before* the first *new* migration your created. And, then you will simply generate a new auto migration instead of an initial migration. For example, if the app was already at migration 0005 and you create migrations 0006, 0007, and 0008:

1. Rollback to just before the first migration you created (0006):

   ```
   python manage.py migrate myapp 0005
   ```
2. Delete all *new* migrations you created (0006, 0007, and 0008)
3. Generate a new auto migration:

   ```
   python manage.py schemamigration --auto myapp
   ```

Either way, you'll end up with just one file encapsulating all of your changes instead of multiple files. Then, you commit this to your source control.

Comment: Chris, Thanks for the guide on the clean up process. So you're suggesting that I keep "clean" migrations and keep them the same in all versions of the repo?


I updated my question since your answer is helpful but I think I didn't communicate some assumptions that are needed to answer the main point of my question.

Comment: The migrations should be committed to your primary or "master" branch in Git parlance, or to whatever particular other branch you are working on, to be eventually merged into master. The migrations go with the model changes. If you models change or you add new models, then everyone who gets your code will need the appropriate migrations along with it.

Comment: As to the issue of initial public release: it doesn't matter whether the public never had access to the code before. You still need to keep all legitimate migrations for the posterity of your codebase.